# Auto increase value php in file based on number entered

Tags: php, formula

I have 5 different variables that I need to calculate. Right now these work, but what I want to do is have the price recalculate every 50 increase. Now, I can code into the form to only allow a maximum purchase of 50 at a time, but I want to allow for as many of each as the person has money for (that is what the numbers are). So I think what I need is a parabola style formula that auto increases every 50, but I don't know exactly what I'm looking for or how to implement it.

```
$resprice = 20000+($cityFetch['residential']*502)+($cityNum*1000);
$comprice = 18000+($cityFetch['commercial']*506)+($cityNum*1000);
$indprice = 23000+($cityFetch['industrial']*508)+($cityNum*1000);
$landprice = 600+($cityFetch['land']*.008);
$milprice = 25000+($cityFetch['military']*512)+($cityNum*1000);
```

EDIT: I was indicated that a loop will work for this.

EDIT3: Finally landed on this, Havvy helped me out on IRC

```
$cityCheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE nation='$nation'");
$cityNum = mysql_num_rows($cityCheck);


function determinePrice($baseCost, $scalar, $current, $bought) {
    $min = $baseCost + $scalar * ($current + 1) + ($cityNum * 1000);
    $max = $baseCost + $scalar * ($current + $bought) + ($cityNum * 1000);
    $average = ($min + $max) / 2;

   return $average * $bought;
}

$resprice = determinePrice(20000, 502, $cityFetch['residential'], $cityFetch['residential']);
$comprice = determinePrice(18000, 506, $cityFetch['commercial'], $cityFetch['commercial']);
$indprice = determinePrice(23000, 508, $cityFetch['industrial'], $cityFetch['industrial']);
$milprice = determinePrice(25000, 502, $cityFetch['residential'], $cityFetch['military']);
$landprice = 600+($cityFetch['land']*.008);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a step size of 1, instead of 50. It's more logical (one less magic number) to not give discounts based on how much you buy at a time, and it would be confusing to new players having a stepwise-linear function.

The reasoning behind this function can be found at http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/.

```
function determinePrice($baseCost, $scalar, $current, $bought) {
    $min = $scalar * ($current + 1) + ($cityNum * 1000);
    $max = $scalar * ($current + $bought) + ($cityNum * 1000);
    $average = ($min + $max) / 2;

   return $average * $bought;
}
```

Using it would look something like this:

$resprice = determinePrice(20000, 502, $cityFetch['residential'], $resBought);

It won't work for land though, because land doesn't include the city price in it. For land, you can copy the function and remove the $cityNum * 1000 portions. You could also add in a $isLand parameter to the signature, and use a ternary operator to add 0 instead.

If you don't like that $cityNum has to already be declared with the proper value before declaring this function, you can always add it to the function signature, making it a pure function.

Comment: So that is just for one of the variables or all five? I'm trying to figure out how I would implement this.

Comment: Syntax corrections: The closing tag for php is `?>`,not `php?>` and function names do not start with `$`. Otherwise your syntax looks good.

Comment: So then where would I put the function in relation to the formula?

Comment: The only value the function requires to be declared before it is $cityNum. If you add that to the signature, it becomes pure, and can declared anywhere. Otherwise it must be declared after $cityNum gets its value.

Comment: This one adds the various zones, but does not deduct the price. How would I go about fixing that?

Answer (score 0):

`$count=1`

`if($count==50)`

`{`

You increase the prices then

`$count=1;`
`}`

`$resprice = 20000+($cityFetch['residential']*502)+($cityNum*1000);`

`$comprice = 18000+($cityFetch['commercial']*506)+($cityNum*1000);`

`$indprice = 23000+($cityFetch['industrial']*508)+($cityNum*1000);`

`$landprice = 600+($cityFetch['land']*.008);`

`$milprice = 25000+($cityFetch['military']*512)+($cityNum*1000);`

`$count++;`

Comment: On condition the form is not refreshed after each buy

Comment: are refreshing after each buy can i know? if you refreshing this needs a flag in data base

Comment: There is a javascript that allows me to see the price after I click off it, if that is what you're asking. If you want to see how it is currently implemented http://pixelnations.net you'd have to register and then it's cities. This is for the zones + land.

Comment: I am certain that I was doing something wrong when attempting to code this into my file. Where you say "You increase the prices then" does that mean you put the $resprice $comprice etc. there?

Comment: yaa.. increase `$resprice` according to your needs

Comment: Okay and this will allow me to make it so that I don't have to set a cap and yet the price will gradually increase based on how many are being bought?

Comment: yes! your are right.. try it and let me know if your requirement is met